# modification in Db Structure

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, orm

I already have a database structure, where I have "orders" table and have following columns
"id","status","sale_Manager_Id" and so on.
According to Previous requirement
One order can  only assigned to one Sale_manager
But now clients wants that one Order can be assigned to Multiple Sale_Managers.
For this purpose now I need to create a new table where I can save order and Sale_Manager.
But now problem is we are using this sale_manager_Id column in multiple query which i have no idea .
Is there is any way i can achieve my requirements without change db query's

Comment: I guess it's not much help to say the previous requirement was flawed (but it was) and I think you will have to revisit all your relevant queries.

Comment: A big change like adding a new table requires changes to how you query the data. ORMs can help limit the amount of code changes you need to do, but won't eliminate it.